# Draw SVG over background image an map SVG coordinates to background coordinates

Tags: svg, yaml, polygon, html-framework-7

I have a f7-card in YAML. There I have a background image and a SVG polygon drawn over it. I want the coordinates of the SVG to be mapped on the background in a scale-invariant way. The goal is to draw the shapes of the rooms (it's an OpenHAB custom widget).

This is my code:

```
uid: anwesenheit_nach_sektor
tags: []
props:
  parameters: []
  parameterGroups: []
timestamp: Mar 12, 2023, 7:50:34 AM
component: f7-card
config:
  style:
    background-image: url('/static/images/top_view.jpg')
    background-size: contain
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position: center
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    display: flex
    align-items: center
    justify-content: center
    overflow: hidden
    opacity: 1
slots:
  default:
    - component: svg
      config:
        height: 100%
        viewBox: 0 0 40 40
        width: 100%
      slots:
        default:
          - component: polygon
            config:
              points: "0,0 11,57.792 0,25.544 29.039,0.208 58,25.792"
              fill: red
              fill-opacity: 0.6
              visible: =items.Test_item.state == "ON"
```

And this is how it looks currently:
[image]

Comment: Please describe what is wrong with the resulting drawing. What should it look like?

Comment: Sounds like you need to map the size (width and depth) of an area to an SVG. So, if the area is 12x8 meter and you have and image reflecting that area (lets say 2400x1600 pixel) you can make the viewBox of the SVG the same dimensions, like `viewBox="0 0 1200 800"` -- so all the values should be in centimeters. Is it something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @chrwahl help I got it working. The viewbox has indeed to be the same size as the image. It's as easy as this. Thank you!